# How to match the single/plural forms and tense of the sentences in NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to mix sentences together.

For example:

```
We are nice guys.
John is a rich boy.
```

Using stanford parser (wrapped by NLTK in python), I can get the syntax tree, and concat the noun phrase and the verbal phrase together. like this:

```
We is a rich boy. 
John are nice guys.
```

I want to do at least some verbal morphing, to turn them into `"We are "` and `"John is"`. It would be harder to match the later nouns to "boys"/"guy".

Also matching tense would be nice, but it doesn't cause as much trouble as the single/plural form matching.

I have searched the Internet, and cannot find good resources to deal with this.

Comment: I'm not sure how complicated your sentences are going to be, but a possible solution to those sentences is to use [chunk](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch07.html) and group them accordingly `PRP` and `VBD`

Comment: The simplest (but not the best) solution is Eliza-like one, i.e. just performing dictionary substitution (similarly as we/I, you/me substitutions in nltk.chat). If your problem is as simple as the example you've given, it would be enough. On the other hand, if you need the full solution you will need full NL-analysis stack.

Comment: Hi @JakubJagiełło. The actually cases I need to deal with would be harder, like wikipedia articles or news articles. But I would like to start with simple cases. What I want to change is not the **subject**, but the **verbal phrase**. I was wondering if there would be a dictionary file I can use to deal with this. I did not find one with word in different morphs.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing `We is`?